# How to prevent direct access to files?

Tags: php

I have a system where users upload image files. I only want specific users to have access to these files and not for anyone to just go to example.php/image.jpg and see any user's image...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following to an .htaccess file, and drop the file into the directory where your images are stored :

To prevent directory browsing:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

To prevent image hotlinking:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|css)$ - [F]
```

Replace mydomain.com with your own domain name.

Comment: Thanks ...Can I still access this via php?

Comment: Hi. Yes, this will be accessible only from scripts in your own domain, but not any other domains.

Comment: -1 this prevents hotlinking and directory browsing but does not allow individualized image permissions on a per-user basis as the question asked

Answer (score 4):

Simply upload them to a directory outside of your web root, and have a php script fetch them and display them to the user if the user meets the proper requirements.

Comment: For example: if the web root is `/var/www/`, you can upload the files to `/var/uploads/`.

Comment: thanks! can you give me an example of how to fetch the file though ? I want the user to be able to download it.

Comment: Use an image function like `imagecreatefrompng` and then `imagepng` to serve it. Don't forget your headers! There's a function like that for most image types.

Answer (score 1):

You can create directory for each user. For example, if username is Jhon, you can create a directory images/jhon/, then use PHP to restrict access to another users directory

Answer (score 0):

Put the in a separate directory, and in that directory create a file called `.htaccess` containing the following:

`deny from all`

This will do what you want.